# CSS issue in IE8 only

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I've inherited a site that uses Google's [GSNewsBar](http://www.google.com/uds/solutions/wizards/newsbar.html). The wizard creates code that includes a linked stylesheet.

On every browser BUT IE8 things display correctly (even IE7!) - 
[image]

But in IE8, the list of search terms doesn't wrap. I've added a local style to the code that overrides the div width, and in IE8 using developer tools, I can see that it's getting the width set correctly (the blue outline in the screenshot below). But the text is not wrapping. Can anyone help me out here? I've tried adding word-wrap:break-word to the override style, which does force it to wrap, but it breaks in the middle of words instead of between words. 
[image]

Here's the entire piece of code, including the override styles:

```
<!-- Begin News Bar Wizard Generated Code++ -->
            <!--
            // Created with a Google AJAX Search Wizard
            //http://www.google.com/uds/solutions/wizards/newsbar.html
            -->

            <!--
            // The Following div element will end up holding the actual newsbar.
            // You can place this anywhere on your page.
            -->
            <div id="newsBar-bar" style="padding-left:10px">
              <span style="color:#a5a599">Loading Google News Results</span>
            </div>

            <!-- Ajax Search Api and Stylesheet
            // Note: If you are already using the AJAX Search API, then do not include it
            //       or its stylesheet again
            -->
            <script src="http://www.google.com/uds/api?file=uds.js&v=1.0&source=uds-nbw"
              type="text/javascript"></script>
            <style type="text/css">
              @import url("http://www.google.com/uds/css/gsearch.css");
            </style>

            <!-- News Bar Code and Stylesheet -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
              window._uds_nbw_donotrepair = true;
            </script>
            <script src="http://www.google.com/uds/solutions/newsbar/gsnewsbar.js?mode=new"
              type="text/javascript"></script>
            <style type="text/css">
              @import url("http://www.google.com/uds/solutions/newsbar/gsnewsbar.css");
            </style>

            <style type="text/css">
                  .gs-result .gs-title * { color: #243c60; }
                  .titleBox_gsnb { line-height: 1.1; padding-bottom: .25em; }
                  .statusBoxRoot_gsnb {
                    width: 300px;
                    /*word-wrap: normal;*/
                }
            </style>

            <script type="text/javascript">
              function LoadNewsBar() {
                var newsBar;
                var options = {
                  largeResultSet : true,
                  title : "Google News Results",
                  horizontal : false,
                  linkTarget : GSearch.LINK_TARGET_BLANK, 
                  resultStyle : GSnewsBar.RESULT_STYLE_COMPRESSED, 
                  autoExecuteList : {
                executeList : [<?php print $google_news_string; ?>]

                  }
                }

                newsBar = new GSnewsBar(document.getElementById("newsBar-bar"), options);
              }
              // arrange for this function to be called during body.onload
              // event processing
              GSearch.setOnLoadCallback(LoadNewsBar);
            </script>
              <!-- ++End News Bar Wizard Generated Code++ -->
```

**UPDATE** - as per the comment below, the search terms wrap correctly when used in a completely blank, otherwise-unstyled page, so there has to be something in the existing styling on the page that's causing this. Here is the Computed Styles content for the selected element (statusBoxRoot_gsnb) from Chrome's element inspector (hugely long, sorry):

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-name: none;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-composite: source-over;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto auto;
-webkit-border-fit: border;
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-border-image: none;
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-box-align: stretch;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-webkit-box-flex-group: 1;
-webkit-box-lines: single;
-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-pack: start;
-webkit-box-reflect: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-color-correction: default;
-webkit-column-break-after: auto;
-webkit-column-break-before: auto;
-webkit-column-break-inside: auto;
-webkit-column-count: auto;
-webkit-column-gap: normal;
-webkit-column-rule-color: #383833;
-webkit-column-rule-style: none;
-webkit-column-rule-width: 0px;
-webkit-column-span: 1;
-webkit-column-width: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing: auto;
-webkit-highlight: none;
-webkit-hyphenate-character: auto;
-webkit-hyphenate-limit-after: auto;
-webkit-hyphenate-limit-before: auto;
-webkit-hyphens: manual;
-webkit-line-break: normal;
-webkit-line-clamp: none;
-webkit-locale: auto;
-webkit-margin-after-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-margin-before-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-marquee-direction: auto;
-webkit-marquee-increment: 6px;
-webkit-marquee-repetition: infinite;
-webkit-marquee-style: scroll;
-webkit-mask-attachment: scroll;
-webkit-mask-box-image: none;
-webkit-mask-clip: border-box;
-webkit-mask-composite: source-over;
-webkit-mask-image: none;
-webkit-mask-origin: border-box;
-webkit-mask-position: 0% 0%;
-webkit-mask-repeat: repeat;
-webkit-mask-size: auto auto;
-webkit-nbsp-mode: normal;
-webkit-perspective: none;
-webkit-perspective-origin: 150px 31px;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-svg-shadow: none;
-webkit-text-combine: none;
-webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: none;
-webkit-text-emphasis-color: #383833;
-webkit-text-emphasis-position: over;
-webkit-text-emphasis-style: none;
-webkit-text-fill-color: #383833;
-webkit-text-security: none;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: #383833;
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
-webkit-transform: none;
-webkit-transform-origin: 150px 31px;
-webkit-transform-style: flat;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
-webkit-transition-property: all;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
-webkit-user-drag: auto;
-webkit-user-modify: read-only;
-webkit-user-select: text;
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
alignment-baseline: auto;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: auto auto;
baseline-shift: baseline;
border-bottom-color: #383833;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-collapse: separate;
border-left-color: #383833;
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: #383833;
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: #383833;
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
bottom: auto;
box-shadow: none;
box-sizing: content-box;
caption-side: top;
clear: none;
clip: auto;
clip-path: none;
clip-rule: nonzero;
color: #383833;
color-interpolation: srgb;
color-interpolation-filters: linearrgb;
color-rendering: auto;
cursor: auto;
direction: ltr;
display: block;
dominant-baseline: auto;
empty-cells: show;
fill: black;
fill-opacity: 1;
fill-rule: nonzero;
filter: none;
float: none;
flood-color: black;
flood-opacity: 1;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
glyph-orientation-horizontal: 0deg;
glyph-orientation-vertical: auto;
height: 62px;
image-rendering: auto;
kerning: 0;
left: auto;
letter-spacing: normal;
lighting-color: white;
line-height: 18px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
marker-end: none;
marker-mid: none;
marker-start: none;
mask: none;
max-height: none;
max-width: none;
min-height: 0px;
min-width: 0px;
opacity: 1;
orphans: 2;
outline-color: #383833;
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
overflow-x: visible;
overflow-y: visible;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
page-break-after: auto;
page-break-before: auto;
page-break-inside: auto;
pointer-events: auto;
position: static;
resize: none;
right: auto;
shape-rendering: auto;
speak: normal;
stop-color: black;
stop-opacity: 1;
stroke: none;
stroke-dasharray: none;
stroke-dashoffset: 0;
stroke-linecap: butt;
stroke-linejoin: miter;
stroke-miterlimit: 4;
stroke-opacity: 1;
stroke-width: 1;
table-layout: auto;
text-align: left;
text-anchor: start;
text-decoration: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-overflow: clip;
text-rendering: auto;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
top: auto;
unicode-bidi: normal;
vector-effect: none;
vertical-align: baseline;
visibility: visible;
white-space: normal;
widows: 2;
width: 300px;
word-break: normal;
word-spacing: 0px;
word-wrap: normal;
writing-mode: lr-tb;
z-index: auto;
zoom: 1;
```

There's no easy way I can find to copy/paste like that from IE8's developer tools, so here's a screenshot of the styles as applied to the selected element (statusBoxRoot_gsnb). I'm hoping someone will see something glaringly obvious in the first few lines so you don't have to read through all of it!

:[image]

Comment: As a side note - You might want to report the issue to Google, so they can add in support for IE8, if it is actually their stylesheet that's messing up.

Comment: I'm just in the process of editing the main post; I took the code posted above and pasted it into a completely empty html file (no other content or styles) and it wraps correctly. So there's got to be something in our existing styles that's causing this, but I'm having some issues figuring out what.

Comment: @EmmyS, is it possible to give us a live link to the page with the problem? because, honestly, no-one will try to debug from screenshots or computed styles..

Comment: @Gaby - sorry, no - it's behind a firewall on our internal dev server.

Comment: @EmmyS, can you tell us if each search term is wrapped in a tag, and if so what tag and what style does it have ?

Comment: @Gaby, each search term is an a href with a class, wrapped in a span with a class. The list of computed styles from inspector is just as long for each of those as the one I posted above for the div they're all wrapped in. The OP would get really long if I posted here, so I've copied the computed styles from both elements and posted them [here](http://www.esthermstrom.com/test/googleNews.html).

Comment: @EmmyS, found the problem and posted an answer/solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem seems to be that IE-8 (*and only that ..*) treats spans with just a space inside as empty (*self-closing tags*).

Google adds that space between the keywords just for this reason, so that they break when needed.

Fortunately they have a added a class to that span so we can trick it with CSS by doing

```
.statusItemSep_gsnb:after{content:' ';}
```

this puts a space right after them and makes IE behave.

Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/V8uHF/

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work inside my template. As I said in the original post, there has to be something in the styles that are in our existing template (included in all the computed styles shown on the link I posted) that is overriding google's styles, because the code as originally created by google works correctly (even in IE8) when it's put into an otherwise empty (i.e. completely unstyled) html page.

Comment: What DOES work, though, is if I change your line to `.statusItemSep_gsbr:after{content:', ';}`. So thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a height on the title element (just the title that is having the issues, not the entire thing)?  Try setting to a fixed px, then to auto if that works.

Comment: It's not the title that's having problems, it's the list of search terms under the title.

Comment: Well, the element that's having the problems, have you tried setting the height attribute?

Comment: That suggestion doesn't really make any sense, but I tried just because IE doesn't make any sense either. Doesn't work - the content of the div still overflows horizontally (doesn't wrap); it just adds a whole bunch of space between the bottom of it and the next div.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure there wasn't a height and width set and the overflow was going on the x axis rather than the y.

Comment: (I couldn't see a height in the firebug results, but just in case).
The only other things I can think of trying are:
    overflow-x: hidden;
    wordwrap: break-word;
To see whether it is an overflow issue (although if it is I'm not sure what to do about it), and to see if it's the string that's formatted weirdly.